# Vs Code unable to install extension if I don't run vs code as root

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In macOS, my Vs Code can't read my extensions if I don't run it as root user.

It happened after I changed owner of `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron` to install an extension called 'Custom CSS and JS Loader'. I don't what is correct permission here, I don't want to reinstall Vs Code currently.

If I run

`ll /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS`

I got this output

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 xyh  wheel   221K Nov 13 09:01 Electron`

Hope to get some help. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the output to that `ll` is:

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 bobvork  staff   221K Feb 11 06:56 Electron`

I had a similar problem recently, where I installed an extension while running as root. I found that `~/.vscode/extensions` contained a file called `.obsolete` that was owned by root. I just deleted the file, ran VS Code again and it was fixed.

Hope this helps you (or someone else)